# Generalization of complete bipartite graphs

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs, algebraic-graph-theory

The concept of complete bipartite graphs can be generalized to define the
complete multipartite graph $K_{r_1, r_2, ..., r_k}$. This graph consists of $k$ sets of
vertices $A_1, A_2, ...,  A_k$, with $|A_i| = r_i$ for each $i$, where all possible inserted edges are present and no intras-et edges are present. Find expressions for the order and size of $K_{r_1, r_2, ..., r_k}$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help, and fewer votes to close, if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far did you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question is likely to be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Many people browsing questions will vote to close without reading the comments.

Comment: I´ve came here looking for help, I don´t know how to start. I´m new in this forum by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick any one of the sets of vertices. How many edges are there connecting each of it's vertices to the rest of the graph? Now sum over all sets, and realize you are counting each edge twice (looking from each end).